# Python builtin idiom to apply a function to each element of an iterable when we don't care about the output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say you have a function that returns `None` (the interesting part being side effects, like logging, updating, saving, pushing through a pipeline...), or a return value you don't really need. Now you want to apply this function to an iterable of objects. How do you do it?

Using `map` is neither elegant nor efficient in some cases, because we need to *consume* it to execute it.

```py
_ = list(map(print, ['hello', 'world']))
```

Fine if the iterable is small, but you don't want to do that for large iterables. So instead you might do this:

```py
def apply(func, *iterables):
    for items in zip(*iterables):
        func(*items)
```

This would give us the effect we desire:

```py
>>> apply(print, ['hello', 'world'])
hello
world
>>> apply(lambda x, y: print(x + y), [1, 2], [3, 4])
4
6
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()
>>> apply(c.update, ['green', 'eggs'])
>>> c
Counter({'g': 3, 'r': 1, 'e': 3, 'n': 1, 's': 1})
```

Isn't there a builtin trick for this? Because `map` seems to be faster for smaller iterables, but there's a high cost on memory, which I guess starts to make it the slowest option at some point:

```py
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> from collections import Counter
>>>
>>> iterable = ['green', 'eggs', 'and', 'ham'] * 10000
>>> timeit("c = Counter(); apply(c.update, iterable);", number=100, globals=globals())
2.7703
>>> timeit("c = Counter(); _ = list(map(c.update, iterable));", number=100, globals=globals())
2.6981
>>>
>>> iterable = ['green', 'eggs', 'and', 'ham'] * 100000
>>> timeit("c = Counter(); apply(c.update, iterable);", number=100, globals=globals())
27.4498
>>> timeit("c = Counter(); _ = list(map(c.update, iterable));", number=100, globals=globals())
30.4676
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in Python built-ins made specifically for this purpose. There are however some design considerations.

There is a memory/speed tradeoff. If you use a list comprehension, there is a resulting list, which is stored in memory.

```
# the result is not assigned anywhere, but the list is still created
[my_func(*args) for args in somme_iterable]
```

Yes, `None` is a singleton but there is a small overhead per list item; for really large iterables it can be substantial. If you use `for` loop, you can simply omit the result.

```
for args in some_iterable:
    my_func(*args)  # result is never stored
```

While se of `map` is discouraged now in favor of list comprehensions, it might give some advantage. If the function is stateless, you can replace map with a parallelized or async version; you can't do the same with list comprehensions or an explicit loop. For smaller/simpler cases, however, it might be an overkill.

```
# imagine we have a module providing a thread/process pool
# there is a ton of reference implementations including here on SO
from my_threadlib import map

# ... the rest of code remains unchanged
map(my_func, iterable)
```

Anyway, the judgement here is subjective and depends more on your code style practices and context in which it is going to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there's nothing in the standard library for this use case that beats memory efficiency and readability of the humble `for` loop. You noticed that `map` can beat the loop in terms of speed - but is this really ever the bottleneck? You should not be building a temporary list of results that you don't need, so `for` loop it is.